# How to declare a 3-dimensional Pyomo-Variable from a .dat file in a tabular format using the * symbol?

Tags: pyomo

I have a 3-dimensional Var in a Pyomo model. Below the pyomo declaration:

```
#test.py

import pyomo.environ as pyo


model = pyo.AbstractModel()

model.REGION = pyo.Set(dimen=2)
model.EMISSION = pyo.Set(dimen=2)
model.YEAR= pyo.Set(dimen=2)

model.AnnualEmissionLimit = pyo.Param(
        model.REGION,
        model.EMISSION,
        model.YEAR,
        default=99999
    )

data = pyo.DataPortal(model=model)
data.load(filename='A.dat')

print(data.data())
print('===========')


instance = model.create_instance(data)
instance.pprint()
print('------------------------')
```

the A.dat file is as follows:

```
set REGION := UTOPIA;
set EMISSION := CO2 NOX;
set YEAR := 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025 2026 2027 2028;

# AnnualEmissionLimit (REGION, EMISSION, YEAR)
param AnnualEmissionLimit default 150 :=
[UTOPIA,*,*]:
    2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025 2026 2027 2028 2029 2030 2031 2032 2033 2034 2035 2036 2037 2038 2039 2040 2041 2042 2043 2044 2045 2046 2047 2048 2049 2050:=
CO2 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999  0
NOX 9999 9999 9999    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  0
;
```

The declaration of param AnnualEmissionLimit (in the A.dat file) is taken from the counterpart of the same problem, as declared on MathProg. In other words, in MathProg it works.

However, in pyomo, once I execute the test.py I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/themis/Desktop/OSeMOSYS/OSeMOSYS-Pyomo/test/test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    data.load(filename='A.dat')
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/dataportal/DataPortal.py", line 166, in load
    status = self._data_manager.process(self._model, self._data, self._default)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/dataportal/plugins/datacommands.py", line 62, in process
    _process_include(['include', self.filename], model, data, default, self.options)
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/dataportal/process_data.py", line 602, in _process_include
    scenarios = parse_data_commands(filename=cmd[1])
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/dataportal/parse_datacmds.py", line 563, in parse_data_commands
    dat_yaccer.parse(data, lexer=dat_lexer, debug=debug)
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 333, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1201, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 192, in call_errorfunc
    r = errorfunc(token)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/themis/miniconda3/envs/OSeMOSYS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/dataportal/parse_datacmds.py", line 452, in p_error
    raise IOError(tmp)
OSError: Syntax error at token 'COLON' with value ':' (line 7, column 13)
```

Probably, there must be an other way to declare this Variable for the case of pyomo.

I do know that is possible to use something like this:

```
param AnnualEmissionLimit default 150 :=
UTOPIA CO2 2019 9999
UTOPIA CO2 2020 9999
UTOPIA CO2 2021 9999
UTOPIA CO2 2022 9999
.....
.....

.....
UTOPIA NOX 2050  0
;
```

However, I do want to keep the initial tabular format (the years in columns), because I do have a lot of other Varaibles and their declaration yields a massive, not user-friendly, .DAT file, if I follow the second format. Note that I cannot change the objective function and the constraints of the model in pyomo, for many reasons.

Is there I way I can keep the tabular format in the A.dat file (years in columns) if I use pyomo?

Thank you in advance

---

I tried many variations of A.dat declaration but I always get error msgs similar to the above

Comment: I would not recommend using a dat file or an AbstractModel for your use-case. If your data is already in tabular format you should be able to convert it to something like a csv file and read the data into Python using a package like Pandas. From there I would recommend using a ConcreteModel from Pyomo and pulling the data you need from a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I do need for the purpose of the application to keep the AbstractModel and the DAT file. I prefer to stay in python framework instead of going back to MathProg. Any thoughts?